# JSON manipulation

Tags: c#, json, foreach, github-api

I'm working on GitHub API and I want to manipulate the JSON response of this API so I have this API code

```
    public class TrendRepo
    {
        public IEnumerable<object> Data;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetTrendingRepos()
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");

        string trendingReposLanguagesUrl = @"https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:>" + (date) + "&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10";

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(trendingReposLanguagesUrl);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.UserAgent = "request";

        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
        var readerResult = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        //var jObj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(readerResult);
        JToken token = JObject.Parse(readerResult);
        var items = token["items"];

        var arr = new List<object>();
        List<dynamic> tripDetailsCollection = new List<dynamic>();

        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (dynamic o in items)
            {
                arr.Add(o.language);
                arr.Add(o.id);
                arr.Add(o.full_name);
                arr.Add(o.html_url);
                arr.Add("             ");
                tripDetailsCollection.AddRange(arr);
            }
        }
        TrendRepo trendRepo = new TrendRepo()
        {
            Data = arr,
        };
        return new JsonResult(trendRepo);

    }
```

which return the response like this

```
{
  "data": [
    "Python",
    319029846,
    "beurtschipper/Depix",
    "https://github.com/beurtschipper/Depix",
    "             ",
    "C++",
    311683390,
    "WerWolv/ImHex",
    "https://github.com/WerWolv/ImHex",
    "             ",
    null,
    316705066,
    "peng-zhihui/PocketLCD",
    "https://github.com/peng-zhihui/PocketLCD",
    "             "
  ]
}
```

but what I want is to be something like this

```
{
  "data": [
    "Python",
    319029846,
    "full_name":[
        "beurtschipper/Depix",
        "beurtschipper/Depix",
        ],
    "https://github.com/beurtschipper/Depix",
    "             ",
    ]
    "data": [
    "C++",
    311683390,
    "full_name":[
        "beurtschipper/Depix",
        "WerWolv/ImHex",,
        ],
    "https://github.com/WerWolv/ImHex",
    "             ",
    ]
    "data": [
    null,
    316705066,
    "full_name":[
        "beurtschipper/Depix",
        "WerWolv/ImHex",,
        ],
    "https://github.com/peng-zhihui/PocketLCD",
    "             "
  ]
}
```

- I tried to add another foreach within the existing one to kind of loop the
  property but it gave me the same result.
- also, I need to select a distinct language which is easy to do but
  the trick move is I want all repos names and count which depend on this
  language within the array, like in the JSON response I want above.

Any help I would be grateful.

Comment: I think I get it. What you need to do is create a class with the definition of what you want to do. The identation you want to apply is because the field needs to be declared as an array

Comment: I try to do this but even when adding a new property to class it just duplicates the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hazeem, Spent bit time to see what we can do get the search results closer to your expectations, basically the way you defined JSON is useless no one would be able to parse, I don't think even serializer would accept for example data collection is not separated by commas, I tied up code a bit to work closer to what you want.

Code:

```
 var tripDetailsCollection = new List<object>();
    var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");

    string trendingReposLanguagesUrl = @"https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:>" + (date) + "&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10";

    var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(trendingReposLanguagesUrl);

    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.UserAgent = "request";

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
    JToken token;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(data ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()))
    {
        var readerResult = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        token = JObject.Parse(readerResult);
    } 
    if (token != null)
    {
        var items = token["items"]; 

        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (dynamic o in items)
            {
                var arr = new
                {
                    data = new List<object>
                {
                    o.language,
                    o.id,
                    o.full_name,
                    o.html_url,
                    "             "
                }
                };
                tripDetailsCollection.Add(arr);
            }
        }
    }
    
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tripDetailsCollection);
```

Result - you should be able loop through the collection and use it elsewhere.

[image]

Comment: No this make any difference because this is not the exact problem I'm facing, as I mentioned that I want to manipulate the JSON response and to be able to put object for each language I have

Comment: @hazem code updated, let see whether this one helps.

Comment: Oh thank you very much I really appreciate your help, and unless I've figured out a way to make this done but I will obviously accept this solution because this is doing what I've asked with even the same and better easier code, but if you don't mind if you have an idea tell me **how to merge or combine objects of the same language**, like if I've two *Python objects* I want to combine them and List the remain data under this language *Python*

Comment: raise a new question with all the relevant details with appropriate tags, not sure this is the place to answer anything irrelevant to this thread.

Comment: see this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65244053/combine-json-objects-with-the-same-value-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

What I need is to wrap my TrendRepo class with the Parent class with the same property values and DeserializeObject of the  instead of  here's the answer and feel free if anything not obvious.

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonPropertyName("items")]
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Items //TrendRepo
{
    [JsonPropertyName("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("full_name")]
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
    public string total_count { get; set; }
}
```

and edit the API like this

```
        var readerResult = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        Root jObj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(readerResult);

        var result = jObj2.Items.Select(x => new
        {
            x.Language,
            x.Id,
            x.Full_Name,
            x.Name
        }).GroupBy(x => x.Language).ToArray();

        return new JsonResult(result);
```